# Converting an integer to a fixed-length string with leading zeros

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, apoc

Ideally I want `toFixed` function in JavaScript https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp I know I can do this with Cypher like below.

```
WITH 3 AS inputNumber
RETURN
  CASE
    WHEN inputNumber < 10 THEN '0' + toString(inputNumber)
    ELSE toString(inputNumber)
  END AS formattedString;
```

but a simple APOC function would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RETURN apoc.number.format(125.4, '0000.000') as value;
```

It returns: `"0125.400"`

Or to match your example:

```
RETURN apoc.number.format(3, '00') as value;
```

returns `"03"`

Comment: thanks! but this only works for floating points

Comment: I updated the answer to show that it can do padding as well

Answer (score 0):

The APOC function apoc.text.lpad will add '0' to the left of a string at a given width.

```
Ref:
https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.text/apoc.text.lpad/
```

> apoc.text.lpad(text,count,delim) YIELD value - left pad the string to
> the given width

Example:
RETURN apoc.text.lpad("3", 2, "0") AS output;

```
╒════════╕
│"output"│
╞════════╡
│"03"    │
└────────┘
```